# Using jQueryUI with Django. How to use it correctly for it to work

Tags: django, jquery-ui

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>


pip install django-jquery-ui
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'jquery_ui',
    ...
)

{% load static %}
<script type='text/javascript' src='{% static 'js/jquery-ui.js' %}'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{% static 'css/jquery-ui/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' %}' />
```

This is what I have done. Yet when I look at the results it does not have the jQuery effects.
It's just plain text, is there a step that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you run `python manage.py collectstatic` ?

Comment: pycharm@glenn-liveconsole3:~/mysite$ python manage.py collectstatic
You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings.
This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?
Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pycharm/static/static'

Comment: The error is suggesting that there is something wrong with your STATIC_ROOT setting. All of your jquery related css files are stored under `/home/pycharm/static/` instead of '/home/pycharm/static/static' right? It cannot find the static folder and thus, it cannot find your jquery-ui.css. Please show your settings.py file.

Comment: Awsome Bud thank you Yes the Problem was   STATICFILES_DIRS = (
 os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static"),
)                          The issue was I had 2 statics in the Static file dirs by removing one of them it allowed me to do the collectstatic

Comment: Well it did the collectstatic but now on the template it just shows text it does not do the jquery motions . Would you know why I have {% load static % } at the top

Comment: Did you find solution on this?